# Create/save file in public folder in React project

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I need create (and after that update) json file from text. I have text from backend and I need save it in public file. I found just this code for React/JavaScript but it just downloads the file and I don't want to download it.

```
const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(response[index])], {type: "text/json;charset=utf-8"});

FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You have two choices; have the user download the file and save it to the shared folder, or have the backend save the file to the shared folder. It's a great security risk to allow random websites the ability to save files wherever they want with no user interaction...

Comment: I understand. But I need some component (or function in javascript) which can save file. It mustn't be to public folder but I need save. I get data from API and than I need save file for example in src folder. What I should use as saver? @HereticMonkey